# Introductory references on the gravitational memory effect

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, asymptotics

I'm currently reading Andrew Strominger's [*Lectures on the Infrared Structure of Gravity and Gauge Theory*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448). While I love the reference, the discussion on the gravitational memory effect feels a bit short, and I'd like to dive deeper into it. What are some references, preferably accessible through the internet, that discuss gravitational memory? I'm looking both for references on memory on its own and for references connecting it to the other corners of the infrared triangle.

Comment: I guess you already know about the playlist on the subject, but nevertheless: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Aml1ToQtt4&list=PLwLjkVy3evOazQ3FoRH-Sz8Eoxx2oriXL&index=9

Comment: @Yukterez I do, but unfortunately it doesn't cover the calculations I'm trying to reproduce. In any case, I think it is a great addition to the post =)

Comment: You can check lectures by Compere (https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07064) and references there in. A toy model for memory effect due to highly energetic massless particles has been discussed here (https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(85)90525-5). Note that, in literature the two terminologies "shock wave" and "impulsive waves" are often interchanged. You can read this review by Penrose : "The geometry of impulsive gravitational waves"